# c - fgets never return \0 and cause a infinite loop

Tags: c, string, while-loop, stdin, fgets

I tried to make a while loop reading some strings from stdin but it never ends

```
 fgets(string,stringlenght,stdin);
 while (string[0] != '\0') {
     ///some stuff here
     fgets(string,stringlenght,stdin);
 }
```

now no matter what I do the loop never end, i tried with ctrl+d and ctrl+z but both never worked.
How can a loop like this come to an end?

Comment: Remember that `fgets()` retains the newline (if room in the array). So an "empty string" will be `"\n"`.

Comment: `while(fgets(...)) {...}`

Comment: @interjay has the right answer here: you have to check the *return value* from `fgets()` to determine EOF rather than inspecting the buffer to determine that.

Comment: What you missed is that when you reach the end of the file and `fgets()` fails to read any more data, **it leaves the old data in the buffer**.  The contents of any buffer you read data into can **never** reliably tell you if any attempt to read data in any way worked or not.  That's what return values do.

Answer (score 1):

> fgets never return \0 and cause a infinite loop

`fgets()` *does* return 0 (aka `NULL`) on end-of-file (and nothing read).

OP's code is not testing the return value of `fgets()`, but a value in a buffer.  Instead, test the function return value.

```
//fgets(string,stringlenght,stdin);
//while (string[0] != '\0') {

while (fgets(string, stringlenght, stdin)) {
```

---

Better example

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  // Lop off \n which may exist near the end of input
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
  ...
```

---

> How can a loop like this come to an end?

For the pedantic: There are ways to make `string[0] != '\0'` false.  One involves reading a *null character*, (e.g. typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd> on select keyboards) but that is implementation dependent.  *Null characters* are rare with text input.

Certainly OP is on a wrong approach and testing the `fgets()` return is the best one.

---

Spelling: lenght -- > length